# How to insert special character in the email HTML?

Tags: html, email, encoding, gmail

In my html I have, following code

`this is a star symbol &#9733`

When I open it in a browser I see:

[image]

But if send this html in email source (using mailgun) in Gmail client I see:

[image]

This happens because in google client `&#9733` turned to `&amp;#9733`

What html code should I send in the email to the star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get that unicode? 
The codes from [Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/) should be working. 
So for your star you can try this one `&#8902;`

Comment: Yes you are right thanks, need semicolon at the end;